# Messages from SNS not reaching SQS queue only when SQS is KMS encrypted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cdk, amazon-sns, amazon-kms

I am using AWS managed keys for encryption of data in my SQS by using the following in CDK:

```js
// Create an SQS queue for buffering the events
const someQueue = new Queue(globalStack, "someQueue", {
  // Recommendation to set VTO to 6 times the lambda timeout
  visibilityTimeout: Duration.seconds(someLambdaTimeout * 6),
  encryption: QueueEncryption.KMS_MANAGED,
  deadLetterQueue: {
    queue: someDlq,
    maxReceiveCount: 5,
  },
});
```

Now when I try to go to console and try to publish some message in the SNS it does not come to the SQS, neither any error message comes up. Everything is in us-east-1, so that should not be a problem. Now, as soon as I disable the encryption from SQS, I am able to receive the messages in SQS when I publish in SNS. I tried doing some research online, and even this article[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-key-management.html#compatibility-with-aws-services) says Every KMS key must have a key policy. Note that you cannot modify the key policy of an AWS managed KMS key for Amazon SQS. The policy for this KMS key includes permissions for all principals in the account (that are authorized to use Amazon SQS) to use encrypted queues., but couldn't find anything helpful. Really confused here. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is no SNS subscription in the code you provided. I'm guessing the subscription should have permission to decrypt the key - where is the subscription defined?